# build spritefont for ios or android in monogame content project

Tags: android, ios, project, monogame

I am using monogame 3.0.1 with VS2010 on Win 7 x64 pc.

I have a spritefont file in my Monogame content project.
When I change Content Processor to MonoGame SpriteFont and Solution Configuration to ios or android, these errors occur:

```
Error   1   Unexpected MonoGame platform 'iOS'! 
Error   1   Unexpected MonoGame platform 'Android'!
```